Splitting of cohomology groups of a split extension
Let $G$ be a group and let $0\rightarrow B\rightarrow A\rightarrow C\rightarrow 0$ be a group split extension of abelian trivial $G$-modules. Given a homomorphism, I put an asterisk below to denote the map induced between the second cohomology groups.
I know that $H^2(G,A)$ does not always split into the direct sum of $H^2(G,B)$ and $H^2(G,C)$, mainly because there are other non-trivial terms in the long exact cohomology sequence associated to the short exact sequence above, namely
$$\cdots\rightarrow H^2(G,B)\rightarrow H^2(G,A)\rightarrow H^2(G,C)\rightarrow \cdots.$$
However, if we call $\iota$ the immersion of $B$ into $A$ and $\pi$ the natural projection of $A$ onto $C$, is it true that $H^2(G,A)=H_1\oplus H_2$, where $H_1=\iota_\ast(H^2(G,B))$ and $H_2\simeq coker\,\iota_*$?
It looks likely that the immersion of $C$ into $A$ will provide a splitting map for $\pi_*$, but so far I cannot prove or disprove it.

As you have an exact sequence, don't you have $\text{Im}(\iota_)= \text{Ker}(\pi_)$ ? So in your context $H_1=H_2$ and it is not a direct sum.

If you know that your initial exact sequence split, we have indeed the relation you want for $H_2=\text{Im}(s_*)$, where $s$ is a section of $\pi$. However this is a decomposition as $G$-modules only if $s$ is a $G$-morphism, which is not one of your assumptions

@ChristopherNicol The OP said that all of $B,A,C$ are trivial $G$-modules, so any splitting homomorphism of abelian groups is a $G$-morphism, no? Anyway, IIRC $H^2(G,-)$ is an additive functor. So, if this is a split exact sequence of $G$-modules $\ldots$? It would be a concern, if we only know that $B$ and $C$ are trivial $G$-modules.

@JyrkiLahtonen thanks I didn't noticed this assumption. So yes the splitting in the category of abelian groups is also a splitting I'm the category of $G$-modules. So we can use the fact that additive functors respect the sum.

@ChristopherNicol, I really meant the cokernel of $\iota_*$. I'm editing the question

@ChristopherNicol, also, I guess it is straightforward, but how can you show that the splitting works?

@AlexDoe it is a general fact in abelian categories : an object $S$ is isomorphic to the direct sum of $A_1$ and $A_2$ if and only if you have morphisms $p_i : S\rightarrow A_i$ and $\iota_i : A_i \rightarrow S$ such that : $p_i \circ \iota_i=\text{Id}$,  $p_i \circ \iota_j=0$,  and $\iota_1\circ p_1 + \iota_2\circ p_2 =\text{Id}$. One you know that it is tautological that an additive functor respect this relation, so it sends a direct sum onto a direct sum.

@ChristopherNicol OK, perfect. I was clearly missing the part about additive functors.
